# DataStax OpsCenter not starting on centos dse cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

I am trying to setup cassandra cluster with 5 nodes. I have installed dse on all nodes and started dse on all the nodes by command.

sudo service dse start

dse is running fine on all nodes.

Now I am trying to configure opscenter following http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/3.2/webhelp/index.html#opsc/install/../../opsc/install/opscInstallRHEL_t.html

When I execute "sudo service opscenterd start", it starts without any problem and even log doesnt show any problem.

But when I try doing "netstat -a | grep 8888", it doesnt show any listener.

Can anybody please help me in identifying issue?

Thanks,
Jenish

Answer (score 5):

I would first figure out if the service is indeed starting.  When you say you checked log, was that /var/log/messages or the opscenter logs? I would check both.

Next I would see if it stays running.  You can also check for the process running with

```
ps -eaf | grep opscenterd
```

If everything is running but not listening on the right port, you should check your opscenterd.conf file for proper port and interface:

```
[webserver]
port = 8888
interface = 127.0.0.1
```

Note that your interface definition may be different - for example, it may be `0.0.0.0` which signifies binding to all interfaces (rather than just localhost as above), but you should validate that it is correct for your environment.